# Getting % complete of SQL Azure Database copy in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, azure, copy, progress, azure-sql-database

I need help with getting the percentage_complete value from sys.dm_database_copies view in Azure to populate a WPF progressbar control in my VB.NET application.

Here's what I am doing:
I have a window that allows a user to create a new account, which will create a Database copy of an existing database in an Azure account and then proceed to insert a new record in a specific table of that database.  While it is copying the database, I want to query the % complete so that I can populate a Progressbar value for the user and to know when it is complete, so that I can continue with the "INSERT INTO" statement.

Here's my code (summary of the error):

```
Dim commandString = "CREATE DATABASE " & dbname.Text & " AS COPY OF DB1;"
'Creates a database copy
Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserID@;Password=XXXXXX")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandString, connection)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Using

'Check % complete
Dim pctValue As Double = 0
Dim timer1 As Double = Timer

'Create the SQL query
commandString = "SELECT percentage_complete FROM sys.dm_database_copies WHERE database_id = '" & dbname.Text & "';"

'Open the connection and keep it open to cycle until copy process is completed
Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userID@XXXXXX;Password=XXXXXX")
    connection.Open()
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(commandString, connection)

    'Start a loop to query % complete and then wait 3 seconds and query again until % complete is >= 100 (100%)
    Do
        Try
            'Return the % complete (range of 0 to 100)
            pctValue = command.ExecuteScalar()
            'Set the Progressbar control value to the returned value
            PctComplete.Value = pctValue
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try

        timer1 = Timer
        Do : Loop Until Timer >= timer1 + 3
    Loop Until pctValue >= 100
    connection.Close()
End Using

'Set % complete to 100% to show it is truly complete to user
PctComplete.Value = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because the row in this DMV is deleted as soon as the database copy is completed so the duration when it has the value 100 is very short. Considering that the view is updated every 30 sec it is impossible to catch that moment.

This DMV is good for monitoring progress and for building progress bars etc. but unfortunately not good for detecting the moment of completion. For the latter I suggest using following T-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_operation_status
WHERE
    major_resource_id = 'dbname'
    AND operation = 'CREATE DATABASE COPY'
    AND state = 2
ORDER BY start_time DESC.
```